# Configure gsutil .boto file to use AWS STS assume_role

Tags: amazon-web-services, token, config, boto, gsutil

Struggling to to work out if the **stand alone** version of gsutil (zip file which can be downloaded from : https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) supports downloading from S3 buckets using (AWS Security Token Service (STS) with an assume_role)?

I am on Windows 7 and wanted to know what the .boto file would look like to make this happen for an assume_role to fetch from an s3 bucket?

thanks

Comment: Read this carefully https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config Basically you run the command `gsutil config` in the terminal and after you follow the authentication instructions, it will output the location of the `.boto` file. In my case (I am using linux) you will see the S3 configuration options between lines 34 - 42.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gsutil uses the older boto library (as opposed to boto3, which was not written with support for GCS resources), which doesn't seem to support AWS session tokens [1] like you'd get back from `assume-role` in the AWS CLI [2].

[1] https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/3767

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html